# Query regarding MAX20480DATEJ/VY+ voltage monitor

Tags: voltage-measurement, input, voltage-monitor

I'm using a [MAX20480DATEJ/VY+](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX20480.pdf) voltage monitor for my design. Out of four inputs, I prefer to set IN1 2.5V at the same time for testing purposes. When I'm running my command, I'm constantly getting a Fault condition detected message. What can I do to make this work? I have shared the schematics for your reference.

Also, it is okay if I keep IN4 as NC and use only 3 inputs?
[image]

Comment: If you configure the monitor for 3V3, it will obviously see 2.5V as an error. For it not to happen, you need to temporarily change the settings in the appropriate registers.

Comment: Okay, kinda new to this. I'm referring to this: https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/256/Maxim_Integrated_MX20480_DS-2450593.pdf

So, should I change address ACC to the datasheet and then configure a different IN channel?

Comment: I don't know what you are referring to by "change address ACC", but you need to change the VIN1 (0x8) register to match the 2.5 V for it not to indicate fault at 2.5 V. If you have managed to configure it for 3.3 V, you should know how to change that to something else.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant change address according to, came out as a typo. Yeah, will try that.